# Java newbie trying to passing a string to an instance java

Tags: java, string, char, instance

Currently, I'm trying to perform a Caesar Cipher in a project I am creating. However, when I try to pass the string into an instance that handles it, it doesn't seem to handle it at all. (Right now I'm ignoring spaces and punctuation).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Cipher {

private String phrase; // phrase that will be encrypted 
private int shift; //number that shifts the letters


///////////////
//Constructor//
//////////////

public Cipher( int new_shift)
{

    shift = new_shift;



}//end of cipher constructor


////////////
//Accessor//
////////////

public int askShift() {


return shift;
}//end of askShift accessor

////////////
//mutators//
////////////

public void changeShift (int newShift) {

shift = newShift;

}//end of changeShift mutator

/////////////
//instances//
/////////////

public String encryptIt(String message) {

char[] charArray = message.toCharArray(); //converts to a character array
//loop that performs the encryption
for (int count = 0; count < charArray.length; count++) {
int shiftNum = 2;
charArray[count] = (char)(((charArray[count] - 'a') + shiftNum) % 26 + 'a');

} // end of for loop    

 message = new String(charArray); //converts the array to a string



return message;
}//end of encrypt instance 


//////////
///Main///
//////////
public static void main(String[] args) {

Cipher cipher = new Cipher(1); //cipher with a shift of one letter
String phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter phrase to be messed with ");
cipher.encryptIt(phrase);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, phrase);




}//end of main function



} //end of cipher class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new encyrpted string is a return value.  The string you're passing in to the method is unchanged.  Try for example

```
String encryption = cipher.encryptIt(phrase); 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, encryption );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign return value to `phrase` again.

```
phrase=cipher.encryptIt(phrase);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change this line

```
cipher.encryptIt(phrase);
```

to

```
phrase = cipher.encryptIt(phrase);
```

in order to change the value of the `phrase` variable.

This is because Java pass by value all the parameters. This means, when you send a variable through a method, you're not sending the actual reference but a copy of the reference.

Comment: it is nothing to do with immutability of String.  It is all because of pass-by-value

Answer (score 0):

One main thing you should know: method parameters are pass-by-value in Java

In brief:

```
public void foo(Bar bar) {
    bar = new Bar(999);
}
public void someMethod() {
    Bar b = new Bar(1);
    foo(b);
    // b is still pointing to Bar(1)
}
```

Therefore, your `message = new String(charArray);` will NOT affect the argument passed to `encryptIt()`